# How to execute a program in linux when the path starts with ".."

Tags: linux

I'm facing with a problem, and though it might be good to ask this dumb question!

How can I run a program in Ubuntu when the path is relative to current directory?

Assume that I'm in `/myDirectory`, and the program to run from here is `../otherDir/program`, so I will need to run something like `. ../otherDir/program`. But it does not work. I have to do something like `cd ..` and then `./otherDir/program`!!

Comment: How does the directory structure look like?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the absolute path?

Comment: You can run `../Dir/to/program` if `program` is executable (and all the directories `..`, `../Dir/` and `../Dir/to/` are accessible, ie readable and executable)

Comment: Assume that I'm in `/myDirectory`, and the program is `../otherDir/program`, so I will need to run something like `. ../otherDir/program`...but it does not work. I have to do something like `cd ..` and then `./otherDir/program`!!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Correct! No need for a `.`! That is the way. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do

```
../your/path/./program
```

where program is located in path folder, or execute regular path as an argument for your binary, for example for shell scripts

```
sh ../your/path/program
```